# Table doesn't exist in the with subquery

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I have a MariaDB database. I am running the [With](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/with) query.

when I run the below query its give me an error that the t1 table doesn't exist

```
with t1 as (select 't1'),

block1 as (

   with inner1 as (
     select * from t1
   )

   select * from inner1
   
),

block2 as (
  
  with b2inner1 as(
    select * from block1
  ),

  b2inner2 as(
    select * from block1
  )
  
  select * from b2inner2

)
select * from block2;
```

However, if I remove the block2 then the query works.

```
with t1 as (select 't1'),

block1 as (

   with inner1 as (
     select * from t1
   )

   select * from inner1
   
)

select * from block1;
```

My question is I haven't used t1 in the block2 subquery then why the query is giving the error.

I think the error occurring because I am selecting the result of the block1 twice in the block2 query. [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=b89129865d968634a30f46e36fed8dd3)

Comment: Start by trying to add the [RECURSIVE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/with/) keyword after the WITH. Your CTE is recursive as it references itself.

Comment: Even If I use recursive then also same error occurred.

Comment: Then there's little things we can do to guess your error without having data and table structure. Prepare a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)